# how to find overlapping record with between date

Tags: mysql, date

I am using MySQL, I have following table structure

```
Id  id2 classId sectionId   validFrom   validTill
------------------------------------------------------
1   1       5       13      2016-01-01  2016-03-30
2   1       5       22      2016-01-15  2016-03-30
3   1       5       23      2016-01-15  2016-04-29
4   1       5       13      2016-04-01  2016-04-30
9   10      6       24      2016-01-17  2016-02-05
10  10      6       25      2016-01-23  2016-02-05
11  10      6       24      2016-01-31  2016-02-05
```

My SQL statement is

```
SELECT count(*) as timeCount FROM TimeTableClassSection a 
WHERE classId=5 AND sectionId=13 AND ((a.ValidFrom BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24') OR (a.ValidTill BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24'))
```

Its returning `timeCount = 0`. But it should return 1 as record with Id=1 falls between this date range `('2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24')`

I am trying to achieve, find out any overlapping record for particular classId & sectionId between provided date range. 
If `classId=5` and `sectionId=13` has `validFrom=2016-01-01` `validTill=2016-03-30` exist, then any date range between this date range `('2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24')` should throw this record as count.

```
If I give date range 2015-12-25 to 2016-09-20 then record count should = 1
If I give date range 2016-2-1 to 2016-02-20 then record count should = 1
If I give date range 2016-2-1 to 2016-09-20 then record count should = 1
```

What wrong I am doing here ... all date format is in YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking if the boundaries are within the date range, but you do not check whether the data range is within the boundaries. You should extend your where criteria:

```
...AND ((a.ValidFrom BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24')
       OR (a.ValidTill BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24')
       OR (a.ValidFrom<'2016-01-18' AND a.ValidTill>'2016-01-24'))
```

Comment: This would only be true at speeds faster than light

Comment: @Strawberry how come?

Comment: Time is linear, therefore the criteria for overlaps is simpler. See my example below.